# Stored procedure not updating record

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an issue with a stored procedure where it is updating one table, but not another, and it only happens on the odd occasion, not all the time. This is the stored procedure:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddTransaction]
    @BeneficiaryName VARCHAR(200),
    @Amount DECIMAL(18,2),
    @Reference VARCHAR(200),
    @Direction INT,
    @Currency INT,
    @CurrencyCulture VARCHAR(5),
    @Status INT,
    @Month INT,
    @Year INT,
    @BankAccountId INT,
    @BusinessId INT,
    @FeeType INT,
    @IncomingPaymentsPercentage DECIMAL(18,2),
    @IncomingPaymentFee DECIMAL(18,2),
    @CompletedPaymentFee DECIMAL(18,2),
    @DateProcessed DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE @oldBalance DECIMAL(18,2)
    DECLARE @newBalance DECIMAL(18,2)
    DECLARE @fee DECIMAL(18,2)
    DECLARE @amountAfterFee DECIMAL(18,2)

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON;
        
        -- lock table 'BankAccounts' till end of transaction
        SELECT @oldBalance = availableBalance
        FROM BankAccounts
        WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)
        WHERE Id = @BankAccountId

        -- set the new balance
        SET @newBalance = @oldBalance + @Amount

        UPDATE BankAccounts SET AvailableBalance = @newBalance WHERE Id = @BankAccountId

        -- insert a new transaction
        IF @FeeType = 1
        BEGIN
            IF @Direction = 1
            BEGIN
                SET @fee = @Amount * (@IncomingPaymentsPercentage / 100)
                SET @amountAfterFee = @Amount - @fee;
            END;
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @fee = 0.00
                SET @amountAfterFee = @Amount
            END;
        END;
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF @Direction = 1
            BEGIN
                SET @amountAfterFee = @Amount - @IncomingPaymentFee
                SET @fee = @IncomingPaymentFee
            END;
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @amountAfterFee = @Amount - @CompletedPaymentFee
                SET @fee = @CompletedPaymentFee
            END;
        END;

        INSERT INTO Transactions
            (BeneficiaryName, amount, Reference, Direction, Currency, CurrencyCulture, DateAdded, [Status], DateProcessed, [Month], [Year], Balance, BankAccountId, AmountAfterFee, Fee)
        VALUES
            (@BeneficiaryName, @Amount, @Reference, @Direction, @Currency, @CurrencyCulture, @DateProcessed, @Status, @DateProcessed, @Month, @Year, @newBalance, @BankAccountId, @amountAfterFee, @fee)
    
    -- now commit the transaction
    COMMIT
```

The insert in to the transactions table is working all the time, but on the odd occasion, the update on the BankAccounts table doesn't happen. This line here:

```sql
UPDATE BankAccounts SET AvailableBalance = @newBalance WHERE Id = @BankAccountId
```

I am not sure if this is anything to do with the lock, but I thought you could still update the locked table within the same transaction. For more info, there could be multiple calls to this stored procedure in the same second, probably no more than 10, but often the issue is when nothing else is accessing the BankAccount record it is updating.

Comment: Without an [mre] this is going to be difficult. Yes, we have the definition of your procedure, but not the values of the parameters, definition of the tables, nor any sample data. If it were the lock, you would get an error as the proc would time out trying to access the table.  This means that most obvious reason is because the `WHERE` in your `UPDATE` returns no rows.

Comment: Sounds like you have a race condition. You record the balance in the transaction row (strangely) - is it correct there? You should be using an update lock for your balance row but that update logic is very verbose. It could be done in a single update statement. No formal need to retrieve, subtract, and then modify using three statements.

Comment: You **need** `UPDLOCK` on the `SELECT` for it to work, `HOLDLOCK` and `TABLOCKX` simply don't do what you think they do. But why is the `SELECT` necessary anyway, you can simplify to `UPDATE BankAccounts SET AvailableBalance +=  @amount, @newBalance = AvailableBalance + @amount, @oldBalance = AvailableBalance WHERE Id = @BankAccountId` and that will do all the locking for you. You could probably even combine the `Transaction` by using an `OUTPUT` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `TABLOCKX` on a `SELECT` statement does not take an X-lock. `SELECT` statements never take X-locks anyway. Furthermore, it is unnecessary and extremely inefficient to lock the entire table.

Secondly, even `HOLDLOCK` is not enough here, because if no data has been modified, the lock will not be taken. **You *must* use `UPDLOCK` for this to work as expected.**

To be honest, you don't actually need the `SELECT` anyway, as the whole thing can be done in one atomic statement:

> I note that `@oldBalance` isn't actually used.

```sql
UPDATE BankAccounts WITH (HOLDLOCK)
SET AvailableBalance +=  @amount,
    @newBalance = AvailableBalance + @amount
WHERE Id = @BankAccountId;
```

You can even combine the `Transaction` insert by using an `OUTPUT` clause, this enables you to entirely remove the `BEGIN TRANSACTION/COMMIT`

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddTransaction]
    @BeneficiaryName VARCHAR(200),
    @Amount DECIMAL(18,2),
    @Reference VARCHAR(200),
    @Direction INT,
    @Currency INT,
    @CurrencyCulture VARCHAR(5),
    @Status INT,
    @Month INT,
    @Year INT,
    @BankAccountId INT,
    @BusinessId INT,
    @FeeType INT,
    @IncomingPaymentsPercentage DECIMAL(18,2),
    @IncomingPaymentFee DECIMAL(18,2),
    @CompletedPaymentFee DECIMAL(18,2),
    @DateProcessed DATETIME
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
DECLARE @fee DECIMAL(18,2);
DECLARE @amountAfterFee DECIMAL(18,2);

SET @fee = CASE WHEN @FeeType = 1 THEN
    CASE WHEN @Direction = 1
        THEN @Amount * (@IncomingPaymentsPercentage / 100)
        ELSE 0.0 END
    ELSE
    CASE WHEN @Direction = 1
        THEN @IncomingPaymentFee
        ELSE @CompletedPaymentFee END
    END;
SET @amountAfterFee = @Amount - @fee;

UPDATE BankAccounts WITH (HOLDLOCK)
SET AvailableBalance += @amount

OUTPUT
    @BeneficiaryName, @Amount, @Reference, @Direction, @Currency,
    @CurrencyCulture, @DateProcessed, @Status, @DateProcessed,
    @Month, @Year, inserted.AvailableBalance, @BankAccountId, @amountAfterFee, @fee

INTO Transactions
   (BeneficiaryName, amount, Reference, Direction, Currency,
    CurrencyCulture, DateAdded, [Status], DateProcessed, [Month], [Year],
    Balance, BankAccountId, AmountAfterFee, Fee)

WHERE Id = @BankAccountId;

GO
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm actually annoyed with myself i didn't actually do that, makes total sense. But also appreciate the lesson on the different locks.

Comment: i am still having issues, even using the one statement to update the BankAccounts record and set the newBalance parameter. For some reason, on some, not all, occasions, the transaction record is inserted with the correct balance, but the BankAccounts record hasn't been updated. I am confused.

Comment: I have also added a try catch and capture the no of records updated and it always appears to be 2, so it has updated the BankAccount record but not with the new balance. Also, i can't implement your second solution above as there is an issue around foreign keys when i try.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `try/catch`, is there an error happening? And where are you checking the number of records updated? Is the `AvailableBalance` null maybe? Yeah you can't do `OUTPUT` into a table with foreign keys, you could do it into a table variable but that doesn't help you.

Comment: The try catch was to capture if anything did fail, which it looks like it isn't. The Account balance is non nullable. It's weird, the balance is right in the new transaction record using the @newBalance, but the AvailableBalance in the BankAccount record is still the old value, so hasn't been updated

Comment: Are there any triggers on that table?

Comment: No triggers. I have just seen it again this morning, same issue, the balance on the transaction record is correct but the availableBalance on the BankAccount record is the old balance.

Comment: Hmm, that is very strange. Was the above your full procedure or is there something else going on? If so I suggest you create a new question showing your full code

Comment: Yes that is the full stores proc., plus your update for the one line update. I have started logging the parameter values before calling the procedure, and everything looks good. It’s so simple but something odd is happening